# Why does ! operator with set -e always succeed even for truthy return values?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I use a system where scripts utilize `set -e`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo 1
true
echo 2
true
echo 3
false
echo notreached
```

If I do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo 1
true
echo 2
true
echo 3
! false
echo reached
```

...the last line is reached. However, if I do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo 1
true
echo 2
true
echo 3
! true
echo reached
```

...the last line is reached even though `! true` should be `false`.

More testing:

```
user@linux:~$ ! false && echo ok
ok
user@linux:~$ ! true && echo ok
user@linux:~$
```

...so in these cases, the `!` operator works correctly.

However, it does not work properly with `set -e`. Why?

Related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 ...although that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that's what the standard says:

> -e
>   When this option is on, when any command fails, the shell immediately shall exit, [...], with the following exceptions:
>
> 2. The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, **a pipeline
>      beginning with the ! reserved word**, or any command of an AND-OR list
>      other than the last.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set

[Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) also points this out, with somewhat different wording.

I think that entry in BashFAQ doesn't even try to spell out the specifics, the phrase "These rules are extremely convoluted" makes that pretty clear. Though the linked pages seem to have more than one would want to know.